# Phoenix Ecto Postgres table not creating

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework

Sup,
in the first place i want you to know that I'm fresh to Phoenix Framework and Elixir. I was working my way through tutorials but I have encountered weird problem. I configured connection and everything is working. But migration files doesn't seem to be executed. I have written following file:

```
defmodule Hangman.Repo.Migrations.CreateWords do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:words) do
      add :content, :string

      timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Which is just a simple table with one field. But Table is not being created in the Database but Ecto thinks that everything is ok:

```
18:22:28.669 [info]  Already up
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This means that the migration has already been performed. There should be a table called `schema_migrations` in your database that stores a reference to each migration as a row in the table with the timestamp (which is the prefix for your migration filename).

When a migration has been performed, it is not possible to run it again without rolling back. You should only do this before you push your changes upstream (i.e. nobody else is depending on it).

```
mix ecto.rollback
mix ecto.migrate
```

If the above doesn't work, you can do a full reset with - this will clear any data in your database:

```
mix do ecto.drop, ecto.create, ecto.migrate
```

Comment: well.. When i try ecto.rollback it's says already down, and when i try to ecto.migrate it says already up

Comment: @Haito what is the path of your migration file?

Comment: @Haito Delete it and create the file again with `mix ecto.gen.migration create_words` - then populate the generated file and try again.

Comment: It Works now <3 Is it normal that file has some weird numbers in name? (20151015172109)

Comment: @Haito You should always use the mix task to generate migrations - this will prepend the timestamp which is used to determine if a migration has been run or not. The migration you created manually would not have been included in the migration list as the timestamp was not present.

Comment: And those numbers decide about run order?

Comment: Those numbers are the datetime that the migration was created, helps keep them in order: 2015, 10, 15, 17:21:09

Answer (score 1):

This look likes it's an really old issue but just for the record
I think `mix ecto.reset` is the single command you are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

Drop the database and create it again

run

```
mix ecto.migrate
```

you are good to go

Comment: Problem fixed what i was doing wrong is creating files manually instead od generating them